# Speech recognition via Sphinx engine produces AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, nlp, text-to-speech, text-extraction, transcription

I am trying to transcribe a video using the code below, but I received the following error:

```
ERROR : transcribe_video_to_text
    audio.close()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Could you please share your ideas to solve this problem, or suggest alternative libraries or AI that could perform the transcription?

Code:

```py
import moviepy.editor as mp
import speech_recognition as sr

def transcribe_video_to_text(video_path):
    # Extract audio from the video
    video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_path)
    audio = video.audio.write_audiofile("temp_audio.wav")

    # Initialize the speech recognition object
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

    # Read the audio file
    with sr.AudioFile("temp_audio.wav") as source:
        audio_data = recognizer.record(source)

    # Perform speech recognition on the audio
    text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio_data, keyword_entries=[('whisper', 1.0)])

    # Remove the temporary audio file
    video.close()
    audio.close()
    os.remove("temp_audio.wav")

    return text

# Provide the path to your video file
video_path = "Gods Architect Antoni Gaudis glorious vision.mp4"

# Transcribe the video to text
transcription = transcribe_video_to_text(video_path)

# Print the resulting transcription
print("Video transcription:")
print(transcription)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the error because the call to `write_audiofile()` returns `None`, and you are trying to call `close()` on it.

You don't need to store the returned value in `audio` in the first place. The updated code below will transcribe your video:

```py
import os

import moviepy.editor as mp
import speech_recognition as sr

def transcribe_video_to_text(video_path):
    # Extract audio from the video
    video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_path)
    video.audio.write_audiofile("temp_audio.wav")

    # Initialize the speech recognition object
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

    # Read the audio file
    with sr.AudioFile("temp_audio.wav") as source:
        audio_data = recognizer.record(source)

    # Perform speech recognition on the audio
    text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio_data)

    video.close()
    # Remove the temporary audio file
    os.remove("temp_audio.wav")

    return text

# Provide the path to your video file
video_path = "Gods Architect Antoni Gaudis glorious vision.mp4"

# Transcribe the video to text
transcription = transcribe_video_to_text(video_path)

# Print the resulting transcription
print("Video transcription:")
print(transcription)
```